# Data set in graph is not showing correctly

Tags: android, achartengine

I have created a graph with one x-axis and two y-axis. The problem is that when I plot the graph with the same set of data set in the y-axis it doesn't overlap. For example if I plot a graph using **left y-axis and x-axis** with values `x(1,2,3,4,5)` and `y(10,20,30,40,50`) it plots a graph along x and y-axis. Similarly when I plot a graph using **right y-axis and x-axis** with the same value, then instead of overlapping it plots a graph in different places. Why does this happen? (Please see the screenshots and the code I have used for plotting this graph)

**Code for plotting graph**

```
public class ChartEngineActivity extends Activity 
{
private GraphicalView mChartView;
private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer(2);
private XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
    setContentView(R.layout.chart_activity);                
        
    List<double[]> x = new ArrayList<double[]>();
    x.add(new double[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5});

    List<double[]> values = new ArrayList<double[]>();
    values.add(new double[] {10, 20, 30, 40, 50});
    
    int[] colors = new int[] { Color.BLUE,Color.YELLOW};
    PointStyle[] styles = new PointStyle[] { PointStyle.CIRCLE, PointStyle.DIAMOND};
    
    renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer(2);
    setRenderer(renderer, colors, styles);
    
    int length = renderer.getSeriesRendererCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
    {
      ((XYSeriesRenderer) renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(i)).setFillPoints(true);
    }       
    
    renderer.setChartTitle("Weight / Temperature");
    renderer.setXLabels(12);
    renderer.setXTitle("Month");        
    renderer.setXAxisMin(1);
    renderer.setXAxisMax(12);
    renderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.CENTER);
        
    
    renderer.setYLabels(12);  
    renderer.setYTitle("Weight", 0);
    renderer.setYTitle("Temperature", 1);
    renderer.setYAxisMin(10, 0);
    renderer.setYAxisMax(60,0);
    renderer.setYAxisMin(10, 1);
    renderer.setYAxisMax(60,1);
    renderer.setYAxisAlign(Align.LEFT, 0);
    renderer.setYAxisAlign(Align.RIGHT, 1);
    renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.LEFT, 0);
    renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT, 1);
    
    renderer.setAxesColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    renderer.setLabelsColor(Color.LTGRAY);         
    renderer.setShowGrid(true);
    renderer.setGridColor(Color.GRAY);
    renderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
    renderer.setPanLimits(new double[] { 0, 12, 0, 12 });
    
    dataset = buildDataset(new String[] {"Body Weight"}, x, values);
    values.clear();     
    values.add(new double[] {10, 20, 30, 40, 50});
    addXYSeries(dataset, new String[] {"Body Temperature"}, x, values, 1);
}

protected void setRenderer(XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer, int[] colors, PointStyle[] styles) 
{
    renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(16);
    renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
    renderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
    renderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
    renderer.setPointSize(5f);
    renderer.setMargins(new int[] { 20, 30, 15, 20 });
    int length = colors.length;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
    {
        XYSeriesRenderer r = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        r.setColor(colors[i]);
        r.setPointStyle(styles[i]);
        renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
    }
}

protected XYMultipleSeriesDataset buildDataset(String[] titles, List<double[]> xValues,
        List<double[]> yValues) 
{
    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    addXYSeries(dataset, titles, xValues, yValues, 0);
    return dataset;
}

public void addXYSeries(XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset, String[] titles, List<double[]> xValues,
        List<double[]> yValues, int scale) 
{
    int length = titles.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
    {
        XYSeries series = new XYSeries(titles[i], scale);
        double[] xV = xValues.get(i);
        double[] yV = yValues.get(i);
        int seriesLength = xV.length;
        for (int k = 0; k < seriesLength; k++) 
        {
            series.add(xV[k], yV[k]);
        }
        dataset.addSeries(series);
    }
}   

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) 
{
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
  Intent intentNotes = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
  this.startActivity(intentNotes);  
  finish();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() 
{
    super.onResume();
    if (mChartView == null) 
    {
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart);
        mChartView = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(this, dataset, renderer);
        renderer.setClickEnabled(true);
        renderer.setSelectableBuffer(100);
        
        mChartView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mChartView.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();              
            }
        });
             
         
        layout.addView(mChartView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    } 
    else 
    {
        mChartView.repaint();
    }
}
}
```

**Screenshot for thats graph that appears**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's a bug in the achartengine.   This happens in the demo of their app too.  It looks like points plotted to the right don't adhere to all of the renderer's styles.

If your chart is static you could try tweaking with the x axis max and min.  This seems to move it around a bit.

```
renderer.setXAxisMax(0);
renderer.setXAxisMin(0);
```

edit:

Try this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
    setContentView(R.layout.chart_activity);                

    List<double[]> x = new ArrayList<double[]>();
    x.add(new double[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5});

    List<double[]> values = new ArrayList<double[]>();
    values.add(new double[] {10, 20, 30, 40, 50});

    int[] colors = new int[] { Color.BLUE,Color.YELLOW,Color.YELLOW};
        PointStyle[] styles = new PointStyle[] { PointStyle.CIRCLE, PointStyle.DIAMOND,
    PointStyle.TRIANGLE, PointStyle.SQUARE };

    renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer(3);
    setRenderer(renderer, colors, styles);

    int length = renderer.getSeriesRendererCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
    {
      ((XYSeriesRenderer) renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(i)).setFillPoints(true);
    }       

    renderer.setChartTitle("Weight / Temperature");
    renderer.setXLabels(12);
    renderer.setXTitle("Month");        
    renderer.setXAxisMin(1);
    renderer.setXAxisMax(12);
    renderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.CENTER);


    renderer.setYLabels(12);  
    renderer.setYTitle("Weight", 0);
    renderer.setYTitle("Temperature", 1);
    renderer.setYAxisMin(10, 0);
    renderer.setYAxisMax(60,0);
    renderer.setYAxisMin(10, 1);
    renderer.setYAxisMax(60,1);
    renderer.setYAxisAlign(Align.LEFT, 0);
    renderer.setYAxisAlign(Align.RIGHT, 1);
    renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.LEFT, 0);
    renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT, 1);

    renderer.setAxesColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    renderer.setLabelsColor(Color.LTGRAY);         
    renderer.setShowGrid(true);
    renderer.setGridColor(Color.GRAY);
    renderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
    renderer.setPanLimits(new double[] { 0, 12, 0, 12 });

    dataset = buildDataset(new String[] {"Body Weight"}, x, values);
    values.clear();
    values.add(new double[] {10, 20, 30, 40, 50});  //whatever values you want to set 
    addXYSeries(dataset, new String[] { "Body Temperature" }, x, values, 0);
    values.clear();     
    values.add(new double[1]);
    addXYSeries(dataset, new String[] {"Body Temperature"}, x, values, 1);
 }
```

This is my code from the demo that works

```
public Intent execute(Context context) {
    String[] titles = new String[] { "Crete" };
    List<double[]> x = new ArrayList<double[]>();
    for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
        x.add(new double[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 });
    }
    List<double[]> values = new ArrayList<double[]>();
    values.add(new double[] { 12.3, 12.5, 13.8, 16.8, 20.4, 24.4, 26.4, 26.1, 23.6, 20.3, 17.2,
    13.9 });
    int[] colors = new int[] { Color.BLUE, Color.YELLOW,  Color.YELLOW,};
    PointStyle[] styles = new PointStyle[] { PointStyle.CIRCLE, PointStyle.DIAMOND, PointStyle.TRIANGLE, PointStyle.SQUARE };
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer(3);
    setRenderer(renderer, colors, styles);
    int length = renderer.getSeriesRendererCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      ((XYSeriesRenderer) renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(i)).setFillPoints(true);
    }
    setChartSettings(renderer, "Average temperature", "Month", "Temperature", 0.5, 12.5, 0, 32, Color.LTGRAY, Color.LTGRAY);
    renderer.setXLabels(12);
    renderer.setYLabels(10);
    renderer.setShowGrid(true);
    renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
    renderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
    renderer.setPanLimits(new double[] { -10, 20, -10, 40 });
    renderer.setZoomLimits(new double[] { -10, 20, -10, 40 });

    renderer.setYTitle("Hours", 1);
    renderer.setYAxisAlign(Align.RIGHT, 1);
    renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.LEFT, 1);
    renderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = buildDataset(titles, x, values);
    values.clear();
    values.add(new double[] { 12.3, 4.9, 5.9, 8.8, 10.8, 11.9, 13.6, 12.8, 11.4, 9.5, 7.5, 5.5 });
    addXYSeries(dataset, new String[] { "Sunshine hours" }, x, values, 0);
    x.clear();
    x.add(new double[1]);
    addXYSeries(dataset, new String[] { "Sunshine hours" }, x, values, 1);
    Intent intent = ChartFactory.getLineChartIntent(context, dataset, renderer, "Average temperature");
    return intent;
}
```

Comment: No, its not working. Do u have any option where i can contruct the same graph without using achartengine.

Comment: Will weight and temperature follow the same values (will they match up like they do now)?

Comment: yeh they follow the same value

Comment: Try the edit.  The only problem is that it will add 2 body temps in the legend.  You could make the color of the second one the same as your background and it will be invisible

Comment: I tried the code u have send but it shows array index out of bound excepyion in  addXYSerie() function

Comment: yeh its working..but i have to  make the color of the second one the same as your background..is it create an problem